# JAVABEANS error cannot find symbol

Tags: java, reflection, javabeans

I try to use javabeans reflection for set/get value of property by name of that property.

When I try to compile this code

```
class TestReflection
{
    public TestReflection()
    {
    }

    private Integer field;

    public Integer getField()
    {
        return this.field;
    }

    public void setField(Integer x)
    {
        this.field = x;
    }

}

//  .
//  .
//  .


TestReflection ref = new TestReflection();
Object value = new PropertyDescriptor("field",
    ref.class).getReadMethod().invoke(ref); // ERROR
```

I got this error:

```
Test.java:84: error: cannot find symbol
                            ref.class).getReadMethod().invoke(ref);
  symbol: class ref
```

How can I fix that error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace `ref.class` with `ref.getClass()`:

```
new PropertyDescriptor("field", ref.getClass())
```

The class literal `.class` is only available on the type, not a variable of that type, i.e.:

```
new PropertyDescriptor("field", TestReflection.class)
```

Note that this is why the compiler throws a `cannot find symbol` error: when it encounters `X.class`, it attempts to search for a class or a type called `X`.

Answer (score 0):

use ref.getClass() method instead of ref.class.